# Where to check Windows service startup history

Tags: windows-7, services, event-log

I suspect one of important services did not start properly on last Windows 7 restart. I have searched eventlogs but there is so many places to search. Is there some place in eventlogs where at least one of the following can be found?

- service startup
- service shutdown
- service startup failure
- service operation failure (crash)

Comment: In order to help you better, can you enlighten why you think this is happening? Any symptoms, etc. You may have made an assumption based on the wrong evidence/knowledge.

Comment: @LPChip - it's Teamviewer service. It is set to automatic startup. Recently I received a complaint that it did not come up after restart. I've found it stopped and there was no problem starting it manually. If I had a log I believe I could determine if there were some manual actions or some failures in place.

Comment: Ah, I've had that happened to me too. Reinstalling teamviewer solved it for me.

Comment: @LPChip, Reinstalling seems to be avoiding the problem rather than fixing it.

Comment: @Pacerier since when is reinstalling not solving a problem? Of course I looked in other solutions first, but weird crashes that are not constantly reproducable ask for drastic measures.

Comment: @LPChip - Pacerier was right. In this case, reinstalling wasn't solving the problem :). The problem was in TeamViewer service startup time which was too long in some cases as eventlog has shown (see the answer). The solution was to increase time limit for service startup. If I remember correctly, I changed it from 30 sec to 60 sec. Problems disappeared.

Comment: @miroxlav ah, good to know. I bet that reinstalling would've pushed the teamviewer service to a later, less busy moment, in the startup queue, and would therefor fix the problem too.

Comment: @LPChip - use advice given in your own answer below to determine exact cause of the crash. :) Sometimes message says nothing special, but sometimes it gives great clue - like in this case, where message was saying that Windows is terminating service startup because maximum allowed time was exceeded.

Comment: @miroxlav I answered the question, but any comments in here are to determinating the problem or to respond to other comments. Its impractical to suddenly move the comments to my answer. Comments are made for side-notes rather than actual answers, which is why I posted the "Reinstall teamviewer" as a comment rather than an actual answer in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services start and stop messages are usually logged to the *System* log with source *Service Control Manager*

Copy and paste the following into a Powershell to search recent logs by the name of your service:

```
$search = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Search Term"; (Get-EventLog -LogName System -Source "Service Control Manager" -after (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Select-Object -Property TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, Message) -match $search | Sort-Object TimeGenerated | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $search = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Search Term"; (Get-EventLog -LogName System
 -Source "Service Control Manager" -after (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Select-Object -Property TimeGenerated,
EntryType, Source, Message) -match $search | Sort-Object TimeGenerated | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
Enter Search Term: monitor

TimeGenerated          EntryType Source                  Message
-------------          --------- ------                  -------
9/10/2020 4:08:22 AM Information Service Control Manager The ServerMonitorService service
                                                         entered the stopped state.
9/10/2020 4:09:40 AM       Error Service Control Manager The ServerMonitorService service
                                                         failed to start due to the following error:
                                                         %%1053
9/10/2020 4:09:40 AM       Error Service Control Manager A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds)
                                                         while waiting for the
                                                         ServerMonitorService service to
                                                         connect.
```

Alternatively, the following just lists all *Service Control Manager* events in the last day:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System  -Source "Service Control Manager" -after (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Sort-Object TimeGenerated | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Example output:

```
 Index Time         EntryType   Source                  InstanceID Message
 ----- ----         ---------   ------                  ---------- -------
298330 Sep 10 04:22 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The defragsvc service entered the
                                                                   stopped state.
298331 Sep 10 04:33 Information Service Control Manager 1073748869 A service was installed in the system.

                                                                   Service Name:  MpKsl69e56c4b
                                                                   Service File Name:
                                                                   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows
                                                                   Defender\Definition Updates\{E6CB5B58-
                                                                   AD9B-48D9-AC69-F0C587EEA983}\MpKsl69e5
                                                                   6c4b.sys
                                                                   Service Type:  kernel mode driver
                                                                   Service Start Type:  system start
                                                                   Service Account:
298333 Sep 10 04:34 Information Service Control Manager 1073748864 The start type of the Background
                                                                   Intelligent Transfer Service service
                                                                   was changed from demand start to auto
                                                                   start.
298332 Sep 10 04:34 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Background Intelligent Transfer
                                                                   Service service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298335 Sep 10 04:34 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The AppXSvc service entered the
                                                                   running state.
298334 Sep 10 04:34 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The StateRepository service entered
                                                                   the running state.
298337 Sep 10 04:35 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The StateRepository service entered
                                                                   the stopped state.
298339 Sep 10 04:36 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Background Intelligent Transfer
                                                                   Service service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298338 Sep 10 04:36 Information Service Control Manager 1073748864 The start type of the Background
                                                                   Intelligent Transfer Service service
                                                                   was changed from auto start to demand
                                                                   start.
298340 Sep 10 04:39 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The AppXSvc service entered the
                                                                   stopped state.
298341 Sep 10 04:49 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The WinHttpAutoProxySvc service
                                                                   entered the stopped state.
298342 Sep 10 04:59 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The DNS Client service entered the
                                                                   stopped state.
298343 Sep 10 05:02 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The VSS service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298344 Sep 10 05:02 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The swprv service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298345 Sep 10 05:05 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The VSS service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298346 Sep 10 05:08 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The swprv service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298347 Sep 10 05:09 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The DNS Client service entered the
                                                                   running state.
298350 Sep 10 05:24 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The VSS service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298351 Sep 10 05:24 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The swprv service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298352 Sep 10 05:27 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The VSS service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298353 Sep 10 05:29 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The DNS Client service entered the
                                                                   stopped state.
298354 Sep 10 05:30 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The swprv service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298355 Sep 10 05:37 Information Service Control Manager 1073748864 The start type of the Windows Modules
                                                                   Installer service was changed from
                                                                   auto start to demand start.
298356 Sep 10 05:39 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Windows Modules Installer service
                                                                   entered the stopped state.
298358 Sep 10 05:41 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The DNS Client service entered the
                                                                   running state.
298357 Sep 10 05:41 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The WinHttpAutoProxySvc service
                                                                   entered the running state.
298359 Sep 10 05:54 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Update Orchestrator Service for
                                                                   Windows Update service entered the
                                                                   running state.
298360 Sep 10 05:54 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The wisvc service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298361 Sep 10 05:54 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Windows Modules Installer service
                                                                   entered the running state.
298363 Sep 10 05:55 Information Service Control Manager 1073748864 The start type of the Background
                                                                   Intelligent Transfer Service service
                                                                   was changed from demand start to auto
                                                                   start.
298362 Sep 10 05:55 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Background Intelligent Transfer
                                                                   Service service entered the running
                                                                   state.
298366 Sep 10 05:56 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The wisvc service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298368 Sep 10 05:57 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Windows Modules Installer service
                                                                   entered the stopped state.
298369 Sep 10 05:57 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Update Orchestrator Service for
                                                                   Windows Update service entered the
                                                                   stopped state.
298371 Sep 10 05:57 Information Service Control Manager 1073748860 The Background Intelligent Transfer
                                                                   Service service entered the stopped
                                                                   state.
298370 Sep 10 05:57 Information Service Control Manager 1073748864 The start type of the Background
                                                                   Intelligent Transfer Service service
                                                                   was changed from auto start to demand
                                                                   start.
```

Answer (score 3):

Services are usually logged to the SYSTEM eventlog.

Comment: @miroxlav done. :) glad I could be of any help. :)

Comment: To find the SYSTEM eventlog, [here's the procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996634(v=exchg.65).aspx)

Comment: @LPChip – thank you for the answer serving many years as the accepted answer